# How create node.js command line tool for adding new files to the specific folder?

Tags: node.js

I've created the web app using `node.js` and I want to create the command line tool which will be adding exists files to the specific directories.

I have following project structure of my web app:

```
-Scripts
-Styles
-Images
-Index.html
-package.json
...
```

I want to add exists files to the scripts files - some `*.js` files and to the styles folder some `*.css` files.

I've found this example - http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm
- Here is the example - how create simple command line but I don't know how work with the files? Where can I store template files and how can I copy these files to the specific project folders?

I have tried this: `cli.js`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var shell = require("shelljs");

shell.exec("npm install ..."); //install dependencies

//Now I want to copy .js files to the scripts directory and .css files to the style directory
//And where store these template files?
```

Comment: I'm a little confused; doesn't your project already include its own dependencies? What precisely is the actual issue? Copying files in Node seems pretty straight-forward.

Comment: I want to add some dependencies too but main question is how copy these files.

Comment: https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra

Comment: Thank you @DaveNewton, where do you recommend to store the template files?

Comment: Doesn't really matter.